# Using the MEGA API, High Level Overview

Tags: javascript, objective-c

I'm looking for help deconstructing the MEGA (mega.co.nz) login process for use within a purely GET/POST context. I can't make sense of the documentation because the majority of it is wrapped in the C++ SDK, which I don't understand. The "Under the Hood" section of the documentation has a variety of URLs and their parameters but it doesn't tell me how make a login request.

So, can anyone help me to find the following info:

- The URL and parameters to make a login request
- The process for decrypting the returned session tokens

I think that with the above info I can work with the API without having to mess with the client SDK.

I added the JavaScript and Objective-C tags because I can read these languages and they are popular.

Answer (score 1):

I think the key is in [this page](https://mega.co.nz/#doc) which contains the following:

> Why do you provide a code module rather than documenting the API
> interface in sufficient detail for me to implement it myself?
>
> Two
> reasons: Complexity/efficiency — Since all of MEGA's crypto logic runs
> on the client side, you'd be looking at a project exceeding 5,000
> lines of code. And, as natural language is rather inefficient when it
> comes to specifying algorithms, the documentation would be similarly
> voluminous. Consistency/interoperability
>
> Ambiguities in the
> specification or its imprecise interpretation would inevitably lead to
> undesired behavioural differences between implementations

To me, this says that you have to use their client-side code, not your own. And that appears to be based on C++. Now if your language of choice can call C++ dlls, then you may be oK, but it sounds like a large job.

Comment: I'm going to let this question sit open for a couple of days and if no one else can pitch in I will mark your answer. I need a better way of asking this because there are already two votes to close. I don't need a walkthrough, and there are libraries for a bunch of languages for crypto stuff so I don't buy Mega's reasoning for limiting the documentation. I think it's just laziness on their part. They don't need to give a tutorial on crypto to do proper documentation, they just need to say "Apply this function to the password, apply this function to the response, etc etc etc"